# first-network sample to run, deploy and invoke on REST protocol

Tags: linux, rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After installing all the prerequisites, I tried cloning/downloading Hyperledger fabric sample first-network on Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 using this command:

```
git clone --tag v1.0.6 https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
```

I was able to successfully start the network using the instructions at  [Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html).

My question is, I need to be able to open up first-network's REST API so that I could invoke/deploy chaincodes using REST protocol on a private network/intranet. Something like this:

```
GET http(s)://10.10.4.244:7050/chaincode
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "status": "OK",
        "message": "mycc"
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

Is there a way to do this using Hyperledger Fabric first-network Sample?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FabricV0.6 provided REST-API, but it's removed from fabric since v1.0. Our project utilizing composer-rest-server(provided by hyperledger composer) to interact with blockchain via REST-API.